# Rails: saving duration between "events"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Long story short, each time a user views a resource, an Event model object is created.  Each event has a duration column.  How can I best save the duration between each event?

```
class Event
  belongs_to :session
end
```

My gut reaction was to use an after_save callback each time a new event was created, calculate the time between "now" and the *previous* event, and save that as the previous event's duration.  However, this creates a "waterfall" effect, as the callback is then executed as the previous event is saved, and then the previous before that, and so on.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd better use after_create callback, this will not trigger while updating previous element

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably keep the last event time in the user's session, because it'd be fast... Whether or not this makes sense may depend on when you need this info, though--is it for reporting, used during interaction, etc.